# Google Places javascript API request all published business locations from my account

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a few Google Map locations added at my business.google.com account.

I'm trying to find a way to request all of them from my account; to include them in my website.

I've already signed up for my API key, and added my trusted domain, but I haven't found a way to request all of them with the API without already knowing either their locations or place ID.

My goal here is to manage only one list at Google account to keep them updated. I don't want double-management, adding and editing them both at my Google account and my website database.

I've figured out that I can download my locations as cvs file, that could be then uploaded to my website database when a location is edited or updated. But is there any way to request a json with them directly with the javascript API from within my website domain in one ajax request?

E.g. 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MY-KEY&someOtherParam=toGetThemAll'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into Google My Business API:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs

There is a REST endpoint to get a list of locations related to one account:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations/list

Comment: Great many thanks for your reply, I didn't realize that my business and places are two different APIs

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer. This is the way SO works http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer